# iOS: Changing view's frame is not working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview in my view controller, and I want dynamically change the its height. Here is the code:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    ...
    self.myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.myScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.myScrollView.bounces = YES;
    self.myScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    ...
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    self.myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 300.0f);    
}

- (void)videoTapGesture:(id)sender
{
    self.myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 600.0f);    
}
```

I want to change scroll view's height dynamically when user taps, but nothing happens. I am not using storyboard, so auto-layout should not be a problem. Why the scroll view is not changing?

Comment: You have `self.myScrollView` and `self.waveformScrollView`. Why should we believe those are the same thing? Also, you do not prove that either one of them is actually in the interface.

Comment: Oops, my bad. They should be the same. In my original code , it is waveformScrollView. I just should thought it would be easier to understand to without the word "waveform".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set breakpoints or add NSLog messages to your videoTapGesture and viewDidLayoutSubviews methods and look for calls to viewDidLayoutSubviews after viedeoTapGesture.  Most likely the size change is happening, but a layout is overriding it immediately so that it has no effect.

Instead of the way you're doing it, save a variable with the desired size so that there's never confusion in your code about what size to be, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat desiredHeight;

- (void)loadView {
    // ... your existing code, then this line:
    self.desiredHeight = 300;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    self.waveformScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, self.desiredHeight);    
}

- (void)videoTapGesture:(id)sender
{
    self.desiredHeight = 600;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Comment: You are right. The new size has been overridden back to the old one.

Answer (score 1):

When you change a view's frame, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called, thus you are resetting the frame again to the incorrect size.

Comment: Yes, it is reset back to the old one